# How do I make a google extension automatically inject js into the page in question

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, wildcard

My current manifest is

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*:\/\/*.*/*"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
```

in this case, the error `Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid host wildcard` occurs when I refresh the extension. is there a better way to do this

Comment: Remove both \ characters.

Comment: @wOxxOm i got the same result with `*://*.*/*`

Comment: Use `*://*/*` as shown in the documentation without adding anything.